# sed - remove multiple lines if contains ends in 'can't find label'

Tags: regex, sed

I have a very large log file (more than 2GB) and would like to remove all debug logs if they contain 'EntityFramework'.

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20405]
      No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.
dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10407]
      'IDCDbContext' disposed.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
      Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
info: Hangfire.PostgreSql.PostgreSqlStorage[0]
      Start installing Hangfire SQL objects...
```

Here I would like to remove the log below and keep the others

```
dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10407]
      'IDCDbContext' disposed.
```

What I've tried so far:

```
sed -i '/^dbug/{:b,N;/^[[:lower:]]/!bb};/.*EntityFramework.*/d' logs
```

However it results in `sed: can't find label for jump to b'`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current error is due to the comma after the `b` label, there must be a semi-colon. Also, you should include `/.*EntityFramework.*/d` (or better, `/EntityFramework/d`) into the command block so that it is executed only inside it:

```sh
sed -i '/^dbug/{:b;N;/^[[:lower:]]/!bb;/EntityFramework/d}' logs
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/mhGIio).

Answer (score 3):

This job is better suited for `awk`:

```sh
awk '!p || !/^[[:blank:]]/ {p = /^dbug:/} !p' file

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20405]
      No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
      Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
info: Hangfire.PostgreSql.PostgreSqlStorage[0]
      Start installing Hangfire SQL objects...
```

We keep a flag `p` to control whether to print or not. `p` is set to `1` when a line starts with `/dbug:/` and remains set for lines following `dbug:` that start with whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program, written and tested in GNU `awk`. Simple explanation would be, using `awk`'s `match` function to match regex `\ndbug:[^\n]*\n[^\n]*` and printing only those lines which are required by OP's shown output(not matched lines only).

```
awk -v RS= 'match($0,/\ndbug:[^\n]*\n[^\n]*/){print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Using record separator capability of `awk` and print the appropriate values needed by OP.

```
awk -v RS='\ndbug:[^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n' '{gsub(/\n+$/,"")}1' Input_file
```